# Is there a way to insert custom text into a heatmap.2?

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using *heatmap.2* to make heatmaps. Sometimes I want to insert a star symbol into a cell element to indicate that this element is statistically significant. Significance has been calculated in another program. Is there a way to insert custom text or graphical elements (star symbol) into a *heatmap.2* heatmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the argument `cellnote`(a matrix of character strings which will be placed within each color cell, e.g. p-value symbols) of `heatmap.2`.

```
library(gplots)

# A 4 x 4 matrix
x <- as.matrix(dist(t(iris[,-5])))

# A 4 x 4 matrix of characters (stars)
labs <- matrix("",4,4)
labs[2,3] <- labs[1,4] <- "*"

# How to use cellnote
p <- heatmap.2(x, cexRow=.8, cexCol=.8, 
               cellnote=labs, notecol="black", notecex=10)
```

[image]